# EditText alignment

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, alignment

I am building a simple text editor. I wanted to align text to left, center and right.

I did following, but does not change the alignment of the text

How do I do this?

```
EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_gcFrontInsideTextData);
    if (command == 0 )
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
        txt.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
    else if (command == 1)
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        txt.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
    else if (command == 2)
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT);
        txt.setLayoutParams(p);
    }
```

Comment: what is the parent view of edit Text? and also if it is a linear layout, what is it's orientation.

Comment: can you describe the intended look of your ui?

Comment: parent edittext is LinearLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` constructor does not take gravity as a parameter - third parameter is layout weight. 
Field `gravity` of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` is in fact layout_gravity, which defines layout aligment inside it's parent.

What you need is

```
if (command == 0 )
{
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use the method `setGravity()` directly on the `EditText` like this:

```
EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_gcFrontInsideTextData);
switch(command)
{
  case 0:
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    break;
  case 1:
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    break;
  case 2:
    txt.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT);
    break;
}
```